# Facebook - posting scheduled posts on pages via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've already read the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts) which isn't quite clear. My question is, just like a page admin can manually add scheduled posts on their page, can my app, with the right access token, do the same? I've already tried using POST requests to set a 'created_time' on a future date but it just posts immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use the `scheduled_publish_time` parameter when creating the post - this parameter is mentioned in the documentation you linked in multiple sections, where the parameters accepted when creating posts are listed, for example, in the 'Status Update' section:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#statuses

Its value should be UNIX timestamp according to the documentation, though in many places in the Facebook API you can also use any date which is parseable by PHP's `strtotime` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) so try that too.

`Time when the page post should go live, this should be between 10 mins and 6 months from the time of publishing the post.`

If you can't get this to work when specifying `published` to false, try setting it to 'true' at creation time

Comment: Just what I needed! Also, could you instruct me on how to retrieve scheduled/unpublished posts? I tried /me/feed using page's access token but all that was there were published posts

Comment: nvm got it. will have to use FQL

Comment: This post helped me https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing

Answer (score 7):

Contributing to the last answer (i'm not allowed to comment).
If you are trying to get the schedules post, you should use `/{page-id}/promotable_posts`. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/ for further details.