# Facebook Schedule post ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share my image and title on Facebook on some particular date and time. I need to use Schedule post. I have gone through this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/scheduled-post , but not getting much idea. Can anyone suggest How can i do this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/scheduled-post
Have you tried this? or do you want to know how to use graph api to schedule post?

Comment: I want to know how to use graph api to schedule post? As i am not getting how will i pass These fields as parameters!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798928/facebook-posting-scheduled-posts-on-pages-via-graph-api Let me know if it doesn't help

Comment: I have created a request to get Page id but it is giving error of unsupported URL.